# How to validate phone number in Zapier?

Tags: typescript, validation, zapier

I'm creating a form in Zapier. In that form there is a field to get phone number as a user input. According to my scenario, I only need to input telephone number with correct format. But here, phone number with any format is accepted.

I want to avoid this and want to know, is there any specific method to validate phone number in Zapier?

Answer (score 1):

There are several 3rd party integrations within Zapier that can be used to validate a phone number. One of them is from Trestle:
https://zapier.com/apps/trestle/integrations

Answer (score 0):

According to me, there are 3 ways:

- You can try Zapier's built-in Formatter app along with Regex operation
- You can also try with a built-in phone number validator
- You can also try with custom javascript code as well

Sample Javascript code:

```
function checkValidPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
  var phoneNumberRegex = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
  return phoneNumberRegex.test(phoneNumber);
}
```